# Laravel 2 instances of BadMethodCallException: 'int does not exist' and 'method does not exist'

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, composer-php, laravel-migrations

I am currently doing migrations in Laravel via the Terminal, and have these two errors when attempting to use `php artisan migrate`; I will print errors below:

```
 BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::int does not exist.

  at /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:100
     96|      */
     97|     public function __call($method, $parameters)
     98|     {
     99|         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
  > 100|             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
    101|                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
    102|             ));
    103|         }
    104| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::__call("int")
      /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/database/migrations/2019_01_29_045824_create_contacts_table.php:15

  2   CreateContactsTable::{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint))
      /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.php:164
```

It seems both errors stem from my CreateContactsTable, so I will print the code from that file below:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateContactsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user1_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user2_id');
            $table->int('room_id')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
            $table->foreign('user1_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('user2_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('contacts');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in line:

```
$table->int('room_id')->unique();
```

There is no `int` method. You should use `integer` instead:

```
$table->integer('room_id')->unique();
```

Comment: Thanks! That error is gone but now I have a new issue, I will print below:

PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'room_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'contacts_room_id_foreign' are incompatible.")
      /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

Answer (score 0):

Change `$table->int` to `$table->integer` because `int` method doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks! That error is gone but now I have a new issue, I will print below: PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'room_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'contacts_room_id_foreign' are incompatible.") /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458 2 PDOStatement::execute() /Users/shaquilenoor/Desktop/chatapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

Comment: Hey @Chakeeel, did you define `id` column on the `rooms` table as a primary key or unique key?